# compare two matched set of elements

Tags: jquery

I need to compare if different selectors returns same matched set of elements.

I came to this easy solution, a little plugin:

```
;(function ($) {
    $.fn.isEqual = function ($selector) {
       return this.add().get().join() === $selector.add().get().join()
    }
})(jQuery);


//e.g of usages: if($('div').isEqual($('#mydiv1,#mydiv2'))
//if($(':checkbox').isEqual($('input[type=checkbox].myclass'))
//if($('div').parents().isEqual($('body div').parents()) etc ...
```

Now i think i'm missing something as all other solutions i have find seems really more elaborate, like this one which seems to be the privileged one:

```
$.fn.sequenceEqual = function(compareTo) {
  if (!compareTo || !compareTo.length || this.length !== compareTo.length) {
    return false;
  }
  for (var i = 0, length = this.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (this[i] !== compareTo[i]) 
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

So, what can be the downside of using $.isEqual plugin?

Comment: What does `.add()` do? Shouldn't it be with an arg which will be added to the selected elements. Actually, `.add().get().join()` is confusion.. Not sure if it is correct and unsure of the return.

Comment: From the [API](http://api.jquery.com/add/), I can't see any benefit of the `add()` method without a selector; can I ask why it's there?

Comment: I'm curious as to what the `isEqual` is doing as well. As `get` is an ajax function as well and like Vega's said, add requires an argument. Other wise it does nothing. I think the `add` and `get` can be removed . Then all `isEqual` would be doing is creating a string that represents and array of elements.

Comment: .add() is for reordering elements, when for example we add document to a set a matched elements to check for potential delegates, like `$('#mydiv').parents().add(document)`. But in mostly all cases, it seems useless. Or if we use a reverse method on a set of elements

Comment: @travis: you're confusing [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) (for Ajax) and [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) (for retrieving DOM nodes from a jQuery collection), they're not equivalent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array's `join()` stringifies an array, so you're relying on the stringified versions of the jQuery set of elements. DOM elements stringify into a string like `[object HTMLDivElement]`, so really you're only comparing the size, order, and types of the elements in each jQuery object.

For example,

```
$("div:first").isEqual($("div:last"))
```

will be true always, because both selectors capture one `<div>` (i.e., they both stringify into "`[object HTMLDivElement]`"), but very rarely should this assertion actually be true.

Even if some browsers *did* supply a way to uniquely identify elements in their string representations, the `toString` behavior of `HTMLElement`s is not specified by any standard, so you'd run the risk of cross-browser compatibility. (As it stands, however, *no* browser does so, so your code doesn't work correctly in any browser.)

Answer (score 1):

As you said *I need to compare if different selectors returns same matched set of elements*

How about this simplified plugin -

```
;(function ($) {
    $.fn.isEqual = function ($selector) {
       return this.is($selector);
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: How about a more complicated selector on the left or right? This is good for one element not for a collection. You going to need to iterate to make sure it works the jQuery way.

Comment: @Vega Please see this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g2UwK/8/), this logs true for multiple matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

The level of comparison that your `.isEqual` and `.sequenceEqual` is different.

`.isEqual` - Compares the `el.toString` of returned selectors. Meaning `<div id="test"></div>` will be same as `<div id="test1"></div>` and `$('#test').isEqual('#test1')` would return true as the comparison is based on `toString` which is `[object HTMLDivElement]`.

`.sequenceEqual` does a node comparision which basically iterates through all elements and compares it one by one.

Above is with the assumption that your `.add` is there by mistake.

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/2QYgp/

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.isEqual = function ($selector) {
           return this.get().join() === $($selector).get().join()
    }
})(jQuery);

$(function () {
    alert($('#test1').isEqual('#test'));
});
```

Comment: add() was used for example in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/WTkau/  where we use a reverse method. This is just an example, of course reverse is useless here. But an other example is when searching for potential delegate using: $(this).parents().add(document)  order is reversed

Answer (score 1):

That `isEqual` assumes that `DOMNode.toString()` produces some string that uniquely identifies DOM nodes. And that is **wrong** assumption. AFAIR `DOMElement.toString()` is not specified by W3C DOM specs so you cannot rely on its results - they will be different in different UAs.

That `sequenceEqual` is correct if the task is to test equality, but not, say, similarity.

Comment: This is correct i was more looking for similarity over than equality as order didn't really matter here.

Answer (score 0):

to start with...

```
if($('div').isEqual('#mydiv1,#mydiv2'))
```

gives an error and sequenceEqual gives "false"